# Azure Logic App - Remove Double Quotes from Queue Message's Raw Input

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-storage-account, azure-queues

I am attempting to send encoded base64 to an Azure Queue using a Logic App. However, the Logic App inserts the message to the queue with double quotes. This is causing problems for my pipeline downstream.

Here is my process:

- Create a JSON message

```
"Compose": {
                "inputs": {
                    "environment": "environment",
                    "group": "group",
                    "job": "job",
                    "project": "project",
                    "variables": {
                        "variable_1": "variable_1",
                        "variable_2": "variable_2"
                    },
                    "version": "version"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            }
```

- Encode the JSON message to base64

```
"Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@base64(outputs('Compose'))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
```

- Add a message to queue

```
"Add_a_message_to_queue": {
                "inputs": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "message": "@string(outputs('Compose_2'))",
                        "queueName": "queueName"
                    },
                    "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
                        "connectionName": "connectionName",
                        "operationId": "operationId",
                        "serviceProviderId": "serviceProviderId"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },

                "type": "ServiceProvider"
            }
```

Comment: Can you add examples of the message and the result in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by cutting *Compose_2* and converting to base64 in *Add_a_message_to_queue*. Correction below:

- Create JSON

```
"Compose": {
                "inputs": {
                    "environment": "environment",
                    "group": "group",
                    "job": "job",
                    "project": "project",
                    "variables": {
                        "variable_1": "variable_1",
                        "variable_2": "variable_2"
                    },
                    "version": "version"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            }
```

- Add a message to queue

```
"Add_a_message_to_queue": {
                "inputs": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "message": "@string(outputs('Compose_2'))",
                        "queueName": "queueName"
                    },
                    "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
                        "connectionName": "connectionName",
                        "operationId": "operationId",
                        "serviceProviderId": "serviceProviderId"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
    "type": "ServiceProvider"
}
```

Comment: Please , try to edit this answer , you can use three backtick (```  ```) blocks to highlight syntax correctly.

Comment: Thanks, Abdurrahim! I appreciate the tip.